# How to pass an img src value on click when it contains php code

Tags: php, jquery

I got a gallery where I pass a proper background image to ad div on click

```
var order = $(this).attr("data-order");
var newBg = "url(/services/workshop_" + order + "@0,2x.jpg";
container.css("backgroundImage", newBg);
```

now I want to transform the whole site into a wordpress theme and a problem emerged. In Wordpress, image sources always contain php code (even when applied as background into the style= attribute), so the link should look like:

```
url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/services/workshop_X@0,2x.jpg)
```

I tried to modify the newBg variable by including the php code in it, but if I do so, the container.css() doesn't work at all. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: I think this should work without any php code. Basically in a way you used to do it before. Because the php code will get translated before the javascript fires

Comment: Well it doesn't. looks like i need to hardcode half of the url in the style= attribute, then just add a part of it on click. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Where this code is located is important. Because if it's js code embedded in a php file, `<?=get_template_directori_uri()?>` will be executed. But it it's a js file, php has nothing to do with it, and the whole thing will be evaluated as js and fail.

Answer (score 0):

ok i figured it out:
i setted the initial background image as inline css, then grabbed the generated link and made the code insert the url modification on a proper position:

```
var order = $(this).attr("data-order");
var txt = container.attr("style");
var n = txt.indexOf("/img")
var newBg = txt.slice(0, n) + "/img/services/concert_" + order + "@0,2x.jpg)";
container.css("backgroundImage", newBg);
```